# how to load python script in interactive shell

Tags: python

I am trying `sudo python get_gps.py -c` and expecting it to load the script and then present the interactive shell to debug the script live as opposed to typing it in manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs:

```
$ python --help
usage: /usr/bin/python2.7 [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables):
-B     : don't write .py[co] files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)
-d     : debug output from parser; also PYTHONDEBUG=x
-E     : ignore PYTHON* environment variables (such as PYTHONPATH)
-h     : print this help message and exit (also --help)
-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
```

use `-i` option

Comment: It's important to point out that -i must immediately follow python. It cannot be after the script name.